# Razor MVC ADO.NET access inherited entity

Tags: entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, ticket-system

I'm currently writing a handy ticketsystem where tickets can be moved to an archive. The ticket entity has many properties and associations to other entities and if I'm right I could just draw an inheritance that inherits all those props and assoc. to an archive entity (see image).

[image: entity framework inheritance]

If my thought is correct I have no idea how to move an entry to the archive in code because I have no clue how to access this inherited archive...
[image: pseudocode that's not working]

Answer (score 1):

Derived entities are part of the collections of their base entities.

To access the first derived entity, you can write

```
db.TicketSet.OfType<Archive>().First()
```

To add a derived entity, simply add it to the base collection.

Comment: ok, that explains my var thatsNotPossible but still don't know how to fix my db.ArchiveSet.Add(db.TicketSet.First(x => x.Id == 123));

Comment: @yourmother: AFAIK, Entity Framework does not have any way to convert a row from a base type to a derived type.  You could delete it, then add a new instance of the derived entity with the same values.